# Dojo CodeGlass works?

Tags: javascript, dojo, pane

In Dojo the sample codes run because it has the references and what not so I understand that even if I copy and paste it, it won't work. However I am pretty sure this code should be fully functional but I don't see why it gives me a blank page. I must be forgetting something.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: false}</script>
    <script src='../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    <script>
    require(["dijit/TitlePane", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(TitlePane, dom){
        var tp = new TitlePane({title:"I'm a TitlePane", content: "Collapse me!"});
        dom.byId("holder").appendChild(tp.domNode);
        tp.startup();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div id="holder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Replace `src='../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'` with the relative URL of dojo.js in your local site, or with `src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js'` (Google CDN).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/megp2yyx

Only change required was that of the `<script src>`.

```
<head>

<script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: false}</script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
<script>
require(["dijit/TitlePane", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(TitlePane, dom){
    var tp = new TitlePane({title:"I'm a TitlePane", content: "Collapse me!"});
    dom.byId("holder").appendChild(tp.domNode);
    tp.startup();
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="holder"></div>
</body>
```